# How do I write an alias for grep -R?

Tags: bash, grep

I end up typing

```
grep -Rni pattern .
```

and awful lot. How do I make this into an alias like

```
alias gr='grep -Rni $@ .'
```

Running that gives:

```
$ gr pattern
grep: pattern: No such file or directory
```

Even though the alias looks fine:

```
$ type gr
gr is aliased to `grep -R $@ .'
```

It seems that the $@ and the . get swapped when it's actually executed.

Comment: It isn't that '$@' and '.' are being swapped - its that '$@' isn't getting substituted (making it empty '') and 'pattern' is getting added to the end of the line.  Your command is becoming 'grep -Rni . pattern'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

make a function instead of alias. Save it in a file eg mylibrary.sh and whenever you want to use the function, source the file

eg mylibrary.sh

```
myfunction(){
 grep -Rni ...
}

#!/bin/bash
source mylibrary.sh
myfunction
```

Comment: sweet! any idea why it has to be a function instead of an alias?

Comment: inside a function, you can do many other things.  eg Flow control. you can also pass in arguments to a function. Its not that easy with aliases. In principle, use alias if your commands are short and simple, otherwise, use functions.

Comment: This function presents `grep: warning: recursive search of stdin`

Answer (score 23):

Try this:

```
$ alias gr='grep -Rnif /dev/stdin . <<<'
$ gr pattern
./path/file:42:    here is the pattern you were looking for
```

This also works:

```
$ alias gr='grep -Rnif - . <<<'
```

Comment: Does some or all of `- . <<<` match up with the `-f` flag?

Comment: @EricHu: The hyphen does. In the first version, `/dev/stdin` serves the same purpose. The dot represents the current directory. The `<<<` is the here-string operator which makes the argument to its right appear as if it were the contents of a file.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson could you please elaborate a little bit more what is doing each parameter (just -R and -f), and what argument corresponds to each parameter? I don't get if -R gets a parameter.

Comment: @FabricioPH: If an option gets a parameter, it must be separated from other options and paired with its parameters. For example (hypothetical): `foo -a bar -bcd baz` in which `-a` gets the parameter `bar` and `-bcd` is really `-b -c -d` all run together and `baz` may be a parameter of `-d` or it may be a positional argument of `foo`. In the case of the `grep` example in my answer, `-R` means "recursive, follow symlinks" and gets no parameter and `-f` means "file" and takes a filename as a parameter, in this case `-` which means stdin. See my comment above yours. Some option formats may differ.

Answer (score -1):

gr.bash :

```
#!/bin/bash

star='*'

grep --include="*$1" -RnHI $2 $star
```

command line : gr .js green