# How do I alias BSD grep to search the current directory recursively with the input?

Tags: bash, shell, grep, zsh, bsd

I have the same problem as the author here: [How do I write an alias for grep -R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2621062/how-do-i-write-an-alias-for-grep-r)

I would like `gr whatever` to execute `grep -nrI whatever .`.

Do I require a function or can I do this with an alias?

Comment: Yes better to use a function as `gr() { grep -nrI "$1" .; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't think of an elegant way to do this with an alias, but it's pretty easy if you define `gr` as a function:

```
$ gr() { grep -nrI $1 .; }
```

Comment: `grep -nrI "$1" .;` would be even better.

Comment: Do you really want to just *ignore* any arguments after the first? I would consider either passing them all through (`"$@"`), or making extra arguments an error -- that way you don't have parameters silently ignored, and users consequently scratching their heads. If someone wants to grep for a string that starts with a dash, for example, you need `-e "$string"`; when you just expand `$1`, you make that impossible (unless you effectively disallow arguments with literal spaces, as by leaving the expansion unquoted).

Answer (score 3):

As noted in `GNU grep manpage` if no directory is passed to `-r` it will work on a current directory:

```
-r, --recursive
  Read all files under each directory, recursively, following symbolic
  links only if they are on the command line.  Note that if no file
  operand is given, grep searches the working directory.  This is
  equivalent to the -d recurse option.
```

So in this case an `alias` is enough:

```
alias gr='grep -nrI'
```

You can now use `gr` normally:

```
$ gr string
```

Comment: The OP is not using gnu grep. AFIK, this doesn't work with BSD grep.

Answer (score 0):

`grap() { if [ "$#" -lt 1 ]; then echo Please enter your search term.; else; grep -nrI "$1" .; fi; }`